# Django Rest Framework model serializer: Set all fields to read only except one

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

The model that I'm using has a lot of fields. I want to be able to set all the fields to be read only except for one i.e. I want to allow only one particular field to be writable. Is there a shortcut to do this?
I'm only aware of using "read_only_fields=('x','y') and I really don't want to type out all the fields especially if I'm going to make changes to the models later. "exclude =" also doesn't apply in this case.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try to override serializer's `__init__` method:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(UserSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    for field in self.fields:
        if field != 'some_required_filed':
            self.fields[field].read_only = True
```

Comment: I am doing similar but it initializes data only for the first API viewset call. In the subsequent calls it is not initializing the data and the validate(self, attr) method is not having the attrs on it. Any ideas why? Thank you.